# How to install PyGame on Python 2.7 (win 64)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pygame, pip

I want to install pygame in python 2.7 on win_64 (windows 10) but I give some Error!

```
 pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

it gives me an error:

```
 Cannot unpack file c:\users\ahmad\appdata\local\temp\pip-xatkk_-    unpack\download.shtml (downloaded from c:\users\ahmad\appdata\local\temp\pip- ki5epe-build, content-type: text/html); cannot detect archive format
 Cannot determine archive format of c:\users\ahmad\appdata\local\temp\pip-ki5epe-build)
```

Running this command:

```
 c:/python34/scripts/pip install http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

gives me :

```
Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-b60d5tho-unpack\pygame 
(downloaded from C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rqmpq4tz-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rqmp\q4tz-build)

 pip install http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz
```

Gives me:

```
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ahmad\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-vt49bq-build\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ahmad\appdata\local\temp\pip-lclwur-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ahmad\appdata\local\temp\pip-vt49bq-build)
```

And some Errors like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to this site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame  and download the version you need. After open cmd, navigate to the folder you downloaded the pygame file and run **pip install file_name.whl**

If you dont have pip installed, download it from this site https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/ navigate again to the folder and run in cmd **python get-pip.py**

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on windows pip is a mess. Consider going on http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml and then downloading an executable or msi.

Comment: It has this Error too:  (     import pygame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.)                    why?

Comment: Also, it says on the page: windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame.

Comment: I did your solve. I downloaded that file from that URL address and  installed that.

Comment: Do you have 32 bit python?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99217/discussion-between-ahmad-and-untitled123).

Answer (score 0):

you maybe find in this web site http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml just search your version you want and install it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30440436)